# Android multi touch gesture recognition

Tags: android, gesture

I am trying to devlop an app in which user create gestures and store information regarding it...but my problem is with recognizing multistroke gesture..."plus" drawn and "a vertical line drawn below horizontal line " appears to be same...Please somebody help..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if you still have a problem I have two suggestions:

1. Have you looked at using the Gesture Builder? It's built into the Android emulator and you can download the apk [here](http://code.google.com/p/quickdroid/downloads/detail?name=com.android.gesture.builder.apk) to put it on your phone.
2. You can always look at downloading this multi-touch gesture library [here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/additional-libraries-classes-official-updates/7421-gestures-multi-touch-library.html) (it will cost you money unfortunately and I don't know how good it is)